# Why my Fourier series not working correct?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

Why does my Fourier not work properly? Where did I do mistake? Is the time domain that I wrote correct or not? The signal equation that I used is this:

[image: Fourier Series]

```
f = 5;    %fixed signal frequency 
fs = 100; %fixed sample frequency (100Hz)
A=1;      %fixed amplitude (1) 
l=1;      % (sec) fixed signal length 

k = app.FourierSerieslength.Value; %myFourier series length is 1 to 21
t = 0:1/fs:l-1/fs;
% y = A*sin(2*pi*f*t*k);
y = (4*A/pi)*1/k*sin(2*pi*f*t*k);  %Fourier series for the square wave signal
plot(app.UIAxes,t,y);
```

My result for Fourier length 3 is:

[image: for Fourier length 3]

and result for Fourier series length 10:

[image: for Fourier series length 10]

Is that correct for length 10?
Why do I not have a square wave?

Another question is that I use this Fourier series for Up-/Downsampling and no change in time-domain views?

Here is my code for upsampling:

```
up = app.UpSamplingSlider.Value;
y_up = zeros(1,length(y)*4);
y_up(1:4:4*length(y)) = y;
y_up = up*y_up;
stem(app.UIAxes3,y_up);
```

Comment: What error do you get? What is the expected result?

Comment: If I insert 21 for the field Fourier series, the resulting signal should approximate a square wave form. In my case it still looks like a sine signal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> y = (4*A/pi)*1/k*sin(2*pi*f*t*k);  %Fourier series for the square wave signal
> ```

No, it's not a series, it's a sine wave. When `k=10`, this reduces to some constant times `sin(pi*(0:99))`, which is zero everywhere (up to numerical precision). Whenever you see the vertical axis have a `10E-14` multiplier, you can be fairly sure it's just zeros up to floating-point precision.

To compute the Fourier series, you need to include the big Σ symbol in the equation:

```
y = zeros(size(t))
for k=1:2:21
   y = y + (4*A/pi)*1/k*sin(2*pi*f*t*k);
end
```

Now when you plot this, you'll see an approximation to the square waveform. The larger the upper limit in the summation, the better the approximation.